# Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 crash and freezes when interacting with USB-C. 16.04 working fine

Tags: usb, asus, freeze, io, usb-c

I have an Asus Zenbook flip S (**UX-370UAR**, Intel Core i7-8550U CPU). It has as **I/O only two USB-C** ports and headphones port. It worked fine with Ubuntu 16.04.

Last year I changed to **18.04** (same is happening with **20.04**): 
  * When plugging in to the charger (USB-C) or plugging the USB adaptor, i.e. when interacting with the USB-C ports, it suddenly **freezes**. The only option is to hard-reset it. 
  * HDMI through the hub sometimes worked, sometimes not (just a matter or keep restarting till it works - super annoying). 
  * Headphones, same same, sometimes ok, sometimes not.

It was so annoying that I needed to go back to **16.04 as it works perfectly** (with Windows 10 too, ehem...), no more fear to disconnect the power cable. 
Has been any kernel changes from 16.04 on the USB-C drivers or I/O managing? I will left a partition with 20.04 to try to solve it with your help.